# Dragging an element relative to initial click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `mousemove` event that I add to an element on a `mousedown` event, then I remove it on a `mouseup` event.

On the mousemove event I'm firing this function where I'm subtracting half of the width and height of X and Y to centre the image:

```
dragImage(e) {
    const width = this.getStyle(e.target, 'width').split('p')[0];
    const height = this.getStyle(e.target, 'height').split('p')[0];
    const X = e.pageX - (window.innerWidth / 2 - window.innerHeight / 2) || e.touches[0].clientX;
    const Y = e.pageY || e.touches[0].clientY;
    const stopTop = Y - (height / 2) > 0;
    const stopBottom = Y + (height / 2) < this.getStyle(e.target.parentNode, 'height').split('p')[0];
    const stopLeft = X - (width / 2) > 0;
    const stopRight = X + (width / 2) < this.getStyle(e.target.parentNode, 'width').split('p')[0];
    const stopTop = Y - (height / 2) > 0;
    const stopBottom = Y + (height / 2) < this.getStyle(e.target.parentNode, 'height').split('p')[0];
    const stopLeft = X - (width / 2) > 0;
    const stopRight = X + (width / 2) < this.getStyle(e.target.parentNode, 'width').split('p')[0];


    // check if element is within vertical bounds
    if (stopTop) {
        this.image.style.bottom = '';
        this.image.style.top = '0px';
    } else if (stopBottom) {
        this.image.style.top = '';
        this.image.style.bottom = '0px';
    } else {
        this.image.style.bottom = '';
        this.image.style.top = `${Y}px`;
    }

    // check if element is within horizontal bounds
    if (stopLeft) {
        this.image.style.right = '';
        this.image.style.left = '0px';
    } else if (stopRight) {
        this.image.style.left = '';
        this.image.style.right = '0px';
    } else {
        this.image.style.right = '';
        this.image.style.left = `${X}px`;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I've tried subtracting the offset of the element from the `pageX` and `pageY` and it gets halfway there, but the element being dragged flickers because every other X/Y value is way off, so the values could be 900, 500, 900, 500 etc.

What could be causing the changing values and am I overcomplicating things? All I am trying to do is drag an image without centring it around the pointer, kept within a boundary.

Thanks.

E - Adding more code for clarification:

I add the first set of mousedown, mouseup and mouseleave events in the constructor:

```
if (this.isMobile) {
        this.image.addEventListener('touchstart', e => this.enableDrag(e));
        this.image.addEventListener('touchend', e => this.disableDrag(e));
        this.image.addEventListener('touchcancel', () => this.disableDrag());
      } else {
        this.image.addEventListener('mousedown', e => this.enableDrag(e));
        this.image.addEventListener('mouseup', e => this.disableDrag(e));
        this.image.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => this.disableDrag());
        this.image.addEventListener('click', e => e.cancelBubble = true);
      }
```

These events add and remove the following function, which enables the dragging:

```
enableDrag(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      e.preventDefault();

      if (this.isMobile) {
        this.image.addEventListener('touchmove', this.dragEvent);
      } else {
        this.image.addEventListener('mousemove', this.dragEvent);
      }
    }

disableDrag() {
      if (this.isMobile) {
        this.image.removeEventListener('touchmove', this.dragEvent);
      } else {
        this.image.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.dragEvent);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle other code to replicate the issue? It's hard to visualize what you're trying to achieve without seeing a working demo.

Comment: @skyline3000 it's part of quite a large project and integrated lots of other bits of code. I'll edit my answer to include more code

Comment: are you trying to centre the image around the cursor as you drag? and why does X use height in the computation? that seems a little weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this: "What could be causing the changing values and am I overcomplicating things? All I am trying to do is drag an image without centring it around the pointer, kept within a boundary.", I'd make three suggestions:

1. your boundary conditions are too complicated, just set `top` and `left` properties and forget about `bottom` and `right`
2. based on the above, i think you want the drag to be offset from where the user initiates the drag. in which case, you have to compute that in the `mousedown` event and just use it here.
3. I haven't done JS code to manipulate the DOM in a while, but back in the day, [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) was the preferred way of getting the position/dimension of a DOM object (rather than querying the DOM straight)

Taking this into account, you can simplify your code as such:

```
dragImage(e) {
    var imageBoundaries = this.image.getBoundingClientRect();
    var containerWidth = this.getStyle(e.target.parentNode, 'width').split('p')[0];
    var containerHeight = this.getStyle(e.target.parentNode, 'height').split('p')[0];

    const X = (e.pageX || e.touches[0].clientX) - offsetX; /* where offsetX is defined as where the user initially clicked on the image in the mousedown event */
    const Y = (e.pageY || e.touches[0].clientY) - offsetY; /* ditto */

    if X <= 0 {
        // hit the left boundary
        X = 0
    } else if X + imageBoundaries.width >= containerWidth {
        // hit the right boundary
        X = containerWidth - imageBoundaries.width
    }

    if Y <= 0 {
        // hit the top boundary
        Y = 0
    } else if Y + imageBoundaries.height >= containerHeight {
        // hit the bottom boundary
        Y = containerHeight - imageBoundaries.height
    }


    this.image.style.left = `${X}px`;
    this.image.style.top = `${Y}px`;

    return false;
}
```

This will clamp the image to the boundary of the window (assuming you want to see the whole image at all times). You can fiddle with the if conditions if you are willing to let the image move out of the viewport a little bit.

Finally, drag and drop is notoriously hard to get right and I would usually run to a third party for this functionality. Something like [Dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula) is a sinch to setup the most common cases of drag and drop that I have seen with. Of course, if this is for learning then yeah, roll your own :)